# Why is this JavaBean XML code written like this?

Tags: spring, struts, javabeans

In the source code for a project I'm working on, there are many definitions of java beans of the form:

```
  <bean id="BeanName" parent="BeanName-parentBean"/>

  <bean id="BeanName-parentBean" abstract="true" parent="RealParentBean"> 
    <property name="foo" value="bar"/>
    <property name="herp" value="derp"/>
  </bean>
```

I don't understand the difference between this and the more succinct:

```
  <bean id="BeanName" parent="RealParentBean"> 
    <property name="foo" value="bar"/>
    <property name="herp" value="derp"/>
  </bean>
```

Are there stylistic or practical reasons for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing, having the parent bean written in it's own bean definition makes it easier to create other beans that refer to the parent bean without a bunch of copy/pasting.

i.e.

```
<bean id="BeanName" parent="BeanName-parentBean"/>
<bean id="BeanName2" parent="BeanName-parentBean"/>
<bean id="BeanName3" parent="BeanName-parentBean"/>

  <bean id="BeanName-parentBean" abstract="true" parent="RealParentBean"> 
    <property name="foo" value="bar"/>
    <property name="herp" value="derp"/>
  </bean>
```

V.S.

```
  <bean id="BeanName" parent="RealParentBean"> 
    <property name="foo" value="bar"/>
    <property name="herp" value="derp"/>
  </bean>
  <bean id="BeanName2" parent="RealParentBean"> 
    <property name="foo" value="bar"/>
    <property name="herp" value="derp"/>
  </bean>
  <bean id="BeanName3" parent="RealParentBean"> 
    <property name="foo" value="bar"/>
    <property name="herp" value="derp"/>
  </bean>
```

Comment: I kind of assumed it had to do something with this, but seeing it helped me understand it a bit better. It seems then that this case is trivial and ineffective since the beans are all the same, but where it would be useful is when you want to extend the parent bean in different ways in "BeanName2" vs "BeanName3"? In other words - is there ever a time you would be required to use three Beans of different names with identical internal values?

Comment: Perhaps you have a few base classes that function as different concrete deserializers, but they all share a parent `AbstractDeserializer`